# JPL DE Documentation

Tags: solar-system, ephemeris

I'm currently trying to write a C++ library that makes accessing binary data from a JPL ephemeris file easier. So far I sifted through the web, trying to find a good and thorough documentation about what is actually stored in there and how to work with the data.

Does anybody know of a PDF/Book or something similar, that explains anything of that sort?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just ran across [this question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/12506/12102) - you may find some of the various answers there helpful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware there are differing formats. SPK is the newer format - the older text format seems to be deprecated.

It's worth having a look at the documentation on [this jplephem python library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jplephem) as it explains the format reasonably well. If you do use SPK, you'll need to read all of [the documentation in NASA's SPK repository](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/FORTRAN/req/spk.html)

I'm not sure if this is from the same author as [this library](http://cow.physics.wisc.edu/~craigm/idl/ephem.html) - worth a read as it discusses the FITS format.

Comment: The python library is really good! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The Python package [Skyfield](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) was written fairly recently, from scratch, by the [same person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85360/brandon-rhodes) who maintains [PyEphem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/). You may find helpful information inside there as well.

I had some difficulty reading a JPL kernel with a variant format, and was pointed to a home-brew python package that solved my problems. The whole thing [is described here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/19263/12102).

If you look at the candid comments here: https://github.com/whiskie14142/spktype01 you'll notice that the task is not always transparent.

There is also the helpful [SPK Required Reading](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/toolkit_docs/C/req/spk.html).